# Can VSCode's color theme correctly highlight all functions and methods (in python)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, pylance

Given the following code snippet,

```py
def hello():
    print("world")


redirect = hello

hello()
redirect()
```

then VSCode using the "Quiet Light" color theme renders it as such:

[image]

Note, that the `redirect` method is not colored as a function/method, but rather as a variable. While this is technically also true, is there a way to "resolve" the variable and color it as a function/method? While this is a simplified example, similar things happen in lots of libraries I use.

//EDIT: In essence, I'd like to highlight all functions/methods, so any pointers in this direction are greatly appreciated.

Comment: pylance is a static analyzer

Comment: @rioV8: I tagged it with pylance as this is the default language server for Python in VSCode, so I thought it might be part of a solution

Comment: you can always add a pull request to pylance to adjust this analysis.